# Getting 504 - REQUEST TIME OUT from Elastic Beanstalk application behind a load balancer in AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services

I've an API backend build NestJS (nodejs) deployed in Elastic Beanstalk inside a container. The Beanstalk environment is behind a Load Balancer.
The issue is that, i can't increase the timeout of the request.

This is the config:

**Platform:**
Docker running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.5.4

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM --platform=linux/amd64 node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /usr/src

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

CMD [ "node", "dist/main.js" ]
```

****Dockerrun.aws.json****

```
{
  "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
  "Image": {
    "Name": "myimage:latest"
  },
  "Ports": [
    {
      "containerPort": "3000"
    }
  ]
}
```

**/.platform/nginx/conf.d/timeout.conf**

```
keepalive_timeout 600s;
proxy_connect_timeout 600s;
proxy_send_timeout 600s; 
proxy_read_timeout 600s; 
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s; 
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;
```

**/.ebextensions/01-increase-timeout.config**

```
option_settings:
    - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:command
      option_name: Timeout
      value: 3000
```

**Elb timeout**

[image]

This is the response that i get after one minute

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>504 Gateway Time-out</title>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <h1>504 Gateway Time-out</h1>
    </center>
    <hr>
    <center>nginx/1.22.1</center>
</body>
```

Any help with this issue will be very appreciated.